# HyperlinkedRelatedField temporarily as read_only

Tags: django-rest-framework

I have field declared in the following way:

```py
field = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    view_name='field-detail',
    source='feature',
    queryset=Field.objects.all()
)
```

Do you know how I can temporarily set such field as read_only ?
Unfortunately such construction doesn't work :(

```py
serializer.Meta.extra_kwargs = {
    'field': {'queryset': None, 'read_only': True}
}
```

it works fine, when field is declared as a ForeignKey in the Model e.g.

```py
class Foo(models.Model):
    field = models.ForeignKey(...)

class FooSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('url', 'field',...)
```

and then (as I mention above), or even:

```py
serializer.Meta.read_only_fields = ('field',)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass `read_only` property while declaring the field when you are using `HyperlinkedRelatedField`

```
field = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(
    view_name='field-detail',
    lookup_field='feature',
    # set read_only to True
    read_only=True 
)
```

> Read docs: [hyperlinkedmodelserializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#hyperlinkedmodelserializer)

Comment: Hello, I have tried but it doesn't work as I get error message: AssertionError: Relational fields should not provide a `queryset` argument, when setting read_only=`True`. Nevertheless it's not the point, I can remove this query argument on the declaration level and it will be fine, but I wan't to make this field read_only in some particular cases, while most of the time I want this field to be  "editable". Thanks